# Selenium Remote Web Driver get console log , C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Кто работал с Selenium , а именно с RemoteWebDriver подскажите как получить лог консоли

При попытке вызвать, driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser) , коллекция всегда пустая

Если пробую использовать вот это :

```
IJavaScriptEngine monitor = new JavaScriptEngine(driver);monitor.JavaScriptConsoleApiCalled += (sender, e) =>
{    if (e.MessageContent.Contains("Trading.PlacingOrderResult"))
    {        message += e.MessageContent;
        findResult = true;    };
};
await monitor.StartEventMonitoring();
```

Config WebDriver

```
var url = _configuration.GetValue<string>("BotConfig:HubUrl");var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
if (_configuration.GetValue<bool>("BotConfig:headless")) options.AddArgument("--headless");options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");options.AddArgument("--verbose");
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(url), options);
return driver;
```

Comment: завершите "...пробую использовать вот это...". что у вас возникло?  вопрос нетривиальный, часть проблем связана с переходом на selenium4 (то есть рецепты в гугле старые)

Comment: не могу достучаться до Nodes через webscoket , и подключится средствами DevTolls для чтения логов консоли

Answer (score 1):

вот так это выглядит в питон и работает замечательно:
вам нужно добавить для своего языка следующее:

```
    import logging
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARN)

- в файле geckodriver.log по умолчанию пишется весь лог

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time
    import sqlite3
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    
    import logging
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARN)
    # # Set the threshold for selenium to WARNING
    # from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER as seleniumLogger
    # seleniumLogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    
    
    
    def send_delayed_keys(element, text, delay=0.3) :
        for c in text :
            endtime = time.time() + delay
            element.send_keys(c)
            time.sleep(endtime - time.time())
    
    #con = sqlite3.connect(r'F:\db\Telegram_Bot\Base.db')
    
    #base = con.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Passport").fetchall()
    
    #for result in base:
    # try:
    #     con.execute(f"ALTER TABLE Passport ADD COLUMN INN TEXT")
    # except:
    #     pass
    # options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    # browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/ru/webdriver/chromedriver', options=options)
    
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    # options.add_argument('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    # options.log(LOGGER)
    # options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/ru/webdriver/geckodriver', options=options)
    
    
    
    browser.get('https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do')
    timeout = 5
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'unichk_0').click()
    browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn-next').click()
    # fAMILY_1 = result[0]
    # nAME_1 = result[1]
    # fATHERNAME_1 = result[2]
    # bIRTHDAY = result[7]
    # pASSP_SERIES = result[9]
    # pASSP_NUMBER = result[10]
    # dELIVERYDATE = result[11]
    time.sleep(2)
    
    # import Action chains 
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
     
    action = ActionChains(browser)
    import pyperclip
    pyperclip.copy('1234567 АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ')
    
    for i in range(5):
        browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').clear()
        browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        # browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').send_keys("АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ")
        # time.sleep(1)
        # ActionChains(browser).send_keys_to_element(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam'), "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуа").perform()
        # time.sleep(2)
        # ActionChains(browser).send_keys_to_element(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam'), Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform()
        # ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('V').perform()
        # ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.TAB).perform()
        # pyperclip.paste()
        # browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').send_keys("АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ")
        send_delayed_keys(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam'), "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ", 0.2)
        time.sleep(2)
    
    
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam').send_keys("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуа")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').send_keys("АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'otch').send_keys("КЛИНИЧЕСКИЙ")
    time.sleep(1)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'bdate').send_keys("25071998")
    time.sleep(2)
    
    # import Action chains 
    # from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
     
    # action = ActionChains(browser)
    # action.click(on_element = browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam')).perform()
    # action.send_keys("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуа").perform()
    
    browser.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('lfam').value='АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ'")
    
    
    time.sleep(21)
    
    browser.close()
```

начало лога в geckodriver.log:

```
1679644019435   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:37917
1679644019440   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--log-level=3" "--remote-debugging-port" "43323" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilezY99Pj"
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
1679644020842   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
1679644020849   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 36047
console.error: "Warning: unrecognized command line flag -log-level\n"
Read port: 36047
WebDriver BiDi listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43323
1679644021031   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.error: ({})
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofilezY99Pj/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43323/devtools/browser/9081a826-057a-4afd-8b61-e649d97aaa4c
console.warn: LoginRecipes: "Falling back to a synchronous message for: https://service.nalog.ru."
1679644093586   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 36047
1679644094585   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:51725
1679644094591   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "48103" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilehr069X"
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

Comment: то есть весь лог запишется в файл на стороне Node ?
у меня 100 Nodes, к слову , которые я подымаю в 100 потоках , это нагрузочное приложение к слову
Nodes запускаются абсолютно на разных  машинах , и я хотел вы вычитывать его через DevTolls , но похоже это не возможно с RemoteWeb driver , Hub не пробрасывает WebSocket connection до ноды , и сама нода подымает DevTolls на локал хосте

Comment: я через remotewebdriver отлично запускал более чем 100 машинок с одного скрипта на одной машинке с одним запущенным geckodriver или chromedriver. полёт нормальный. драйвера не виснут неделями.

Comment: с другой стороны. запущенные браузеры, процессы отдельные, лог можно вести отдельно, хоть в постгрес записывайте, хоть в graylog.  только каждому логу персональное имя в настройках укажите.